# cross domain requests with GWT

Tags: java, gwt, get, request, response

Getting this error on chrome while trying to make cross-domain requests with GWT application.

```
Origin http://127.0.0.1:8888 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I have tried the following code for sending GET request.

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.http.client.Request;
import com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder;
import com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestCallback;
import com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestException;
import com.google.gwt.http.client.Response;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;


public class Detracker implements EntryPoint {
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        doGet("http://www.google.com");
    }

    public static void doGet(String url) {
        RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, url);

        try {
            builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
                public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
                    // Code omitted for clarity
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponseReceived(Request request,
                        Response response) {
                    final Label msgLabel = new Label();
                    msgLabel.setText(response.getText());
                    RootPanel.get("resultContainer").add(msgLabel);
                }
            });

        } catch (RequestException e) {
            // Code omitted for clarity
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not allowed, unfortunately, due to security constraints

Comment: is there any trick/hack available for this

Comment: not that I'm aware of. we ended up writing a little servlet or jsp that runs in the back end of our GWT app and acts as something of a proxy. it's running actual Java, so it can make whatever requests it wants to, passing the GET/POST parameters as appropriate, getting the response, sending it back to the GWT client. I'm sorry I can't share the code, but it belongs to my employer.

Comment: its ok, actually i also have done this thing with actual java but just not able to do with GWT. So, I think you will be able to tell me that how you are using actual java in the servlet.

Comment: Read this: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/Xsite.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around and came out with this working solution. :)

```
String message = "";


try {
    URL url = new URL("working-url");
    URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
    urlConn.setReadTimeout(100000);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));
    String line;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        message = message.concat(line);
    }
    reader.close();

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
message = e.getMessage();
} catch (IOException e) {
message = e.getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [JSONP](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/using_gwt_for_json_mashups.html) for crossdomain requests. (But there exist some restrictions - you can only GET method)

Another way is to use GWT's servlet to get result of request and return it to client. Also exist some hacks with iframe, html5 also can make crossdomain requests.

Comment: I was trying the same from GWT's servlet, But it always throws exceptions like Source Not Found For Type. I have also tried GWTQuery, but still not able to implement it correctly. Do you have any idea of any working example available on the internet.
THANKS

Answer (score 0):

See [HITCH HIKER'S GUIDE TO JAVA](http://h2g2java.blessedgeek.com/2011/06/gwt-requestbuilder-vs-rpc-vs-script.html)